# Efficient way to figure out which bit is set in a 64 bit quantity

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

This is effectively log base 2, but I do not have access to this functionality in the environment I'm in. Manually walking through the bits to verify them is unacceptably slow. If it were just 4 bits, I could probably index it and waste some space in an array, but with 64 bits it is not viable.

Any clever constant time method to find which bit is set ? (The quantity is a 64-bit number).

EDIT: To clarify, there is a single bit set in the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest method I know of uses a [DeBruijn Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence).

[Find the log base 2 of an N-bit integer in O(lg(N)) operations with multiply and lookup](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogDeBruijn)

Note that in lg(N), N is the number of bits, not the number of the highest set bit. So it's constant time for any N-bit number.

If you know that the number is an exact power of 2 (i.e. there is only 1 bit set), there is an even faster method just below that.

That hack is for 32 bits. I seem to recall seeing a 64 bit example somewhere, but can't track it down at the moment. Worst case, you run it twice: once for the high 32 bits and once for the low 32 bits.

Comment: Thanks! I found exactly the stuff in the latter example on De Bruijn sequence. How exactly it works, I have some work to figure out.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want the position of the most significant bit that is set. Do a binary search. If the entire value is 0, no bits are set. If the top 32 bits are 0, then the bit is in the bottom 32 bits; else it is in the high half. Then recurse on the two 16-bit halves of the appropriate 32 bits. Recurse until you are down to a 4-bit value and use your look-up table. (Or recurse down to a 1-bit value.) You just need to keep track of which half you used at each recursion level.

Comment: +1, but don't use recursion unless you can verify that the compiler is converting it into a loop.

Comment: @japreiss - Yeah, for efficiency it should be done as a loop (or, better yet, simply unrolled; we're only talking about 4 levels if the look-up table is used).

Comment: I was thinking of something on similar lines. But rather than go down to 4-bits, if we could 8-bits and use a 256-size array, would it be possible to use the 'holes' for an other set of 8 bits?

Comment: @Kumar - Sure, a 256-size lookup table would speed things up that much more. I don't understand your comment about 'holes'--what holes, and what would they be used for?

Comment: If we were to use a 256 size array, the lookup for 8-bits is speeded up to constant time. We'll however use only 8 of the 256 entries, and the rest of them are empty, or 'holes'. Now, since there are more blocks of 8-bits, instead of using more 256-sized arrays, can we interleave multiple of these in a non overlapping manner to reduce space consumption ?

Comment: Take this illustration. To handle 8 bits as 2 4-bit quantities, if we use an array of size 10,

    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    1 1   1       1
        2     2 2   2
If the first block are 4-bits are stored in positions 1, 2, 4, 8.. and the second block is stored starting at 6 in positions 6, 7, 9, 3 (wrap around), we can do this in 10 bits with 2 unused spaces instead of 16 bits with 8 unused spaces. Can this be generalized to larger sizes?

Comment: @Ted Hopp, Apologize, not able to get the formatting right in the comment.. hopefully the explanation should help.

Comment: @Kumar - Perhaps you are using a different definition of a look-up table? With my definition, an 8-bit quantity can have one of 256 values, so you need a table of 256 entries; you don't use only 8 of the entries and there are no holes. Also, I don't understand why you would need two separate tables for 4-bit look-up stored in some interleaved fashion. Wouldn't the tables be identical?

Comment: @Ted, As I clarified, the number has a single bit set. So, for 8-bits, only 8 entries of the 256 are used.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are powers of 2 and you have a bit count instruction you could do:

```
bitcount(x-1)
```

e.g.

```
  x      x-1     bitcount(x-1)  

  b100   b011    2  
  b001   b000    0
```

Note this will not work if the numbers are not powers of 2.

EDIT

Here is a 64bit version of the De Brujin method:

```
static const int log2_table[64] = {0, 1, 2, 7, 3, 13, 8, 19, 4, 25, 14, 28, 9, 34, 
                                   20, 40, 5, 17, 26, 38, 15, 46, 29, 48, 10, 31,
                                   35, 54, 21, 50, 41, 57, 63, 6, 12, 18, 24, 27, 
                                   33, 39, 16, 37, 45, 47, 30, 53, 49, 56, 62, 11, 
                                   23, 32, 36, 44, 52, 55, 61, 22, 43, 51, 60, 42, 59, 58};

int fastlog2(unsigned long long x) {
    return log2_table[ ( x * 0x218a392cd3d5dbfULL ) >> 58 ];
}
```

Test code:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<64;i++) {
        unsigned long long x=1ULL<<i;
        printf("0x%llu -> %d\n",x,fastlog2(x));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The magic 64bit number is an order 6 binary De Brujin sequence.

Multiplying by a power of 2 is equivalent to shifting this number up by a certain number of places.

This means that the top 6 bits of the multiplication result correspond to a different subsequence of 6 digits for each input number.  The De Brujin sequence has the property that each subsequence is unique, so we can construct an appropriate lookup table to turn back from subsequence to position of the set bit.

Comment: Yes, gcc provides a bit_ffs kind of instruction, but I understand this is microcoded on some platforms, and so not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some modern Intel CPU, you can use hardware 
supported "POPulation CouNT" assembly instruction:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT

for Unix/gcc, you can use macro:

```
#include <smmintrin.h>
uint64_t x;
int c = _mm_popcnt_u64(x);
```